# Should a question be deleted if author provides no additional information?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Here is the example of such a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299600/the-form-fails-to-popup-in-windows-8). As of today, no information has been provided after 2.5 months.

Such a question should be deleted - because the person posting such a question doesn't want to have it answered. Do you agree?

Answer (score 7):

If there isn't enough information provided in the question for someone to answer it, it should have been [**closed** (err, put on hold)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) by you and other members of the community.

Closure is generally a prerequisite for deletion, assuming that the question is not obviously spam or otherwise inappropriate. That gives the asker an opportunity to read the comments and fix/improve the question, then have it re-opened by the same process. And then yes, if they still fail to do this, closed questions should be (and are) eventually deleted.

Beyond that, we do have a mechanism in place similar to the one you describe. [The system automatically deletes unlocked, unanswered questions with a score of 0 and low views after one year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). But this question doesn't qualify, because it has 3 comments—automatic deletion requires less than 2.

Of course, it might also have qualified under the other rule: unlocked questions more than 30 days old that have no answers and have a score of -1 or less are automatically deleted by the system. Which is why you should also **downvote** questions that do not contain enough information to be reasonably answered or that you do not think belong on the site.

Comment: Ironically it has 3 comments because of the OP... but a long way to go until the year is up. A downvote however is the simple way to delete it as soon as the auto-delete script runs.

Comment: Worse, now it has [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17782532/366904).

Comment: Downvote is not the solution in such a situations. For example - question was asked - it is more or less well formated - but without any additional information. You aks for this information - but you will not downvote at that time cause you dont know - maybe you will become this information soon... After some weeks no one take a care of it anymore - and it will not be closed....

Comment: @MikroDel Downvoting is not just for questions that are badly formatted. That's what edits are for. If a question does not contain enough information to be answered, it should be downvoted and closed. If the information does show up, you can always remove your downvote and vote to re-open.

Comment: In this situation - I have downvoted it and flagged it - to delete or close.  Cause I havent enough points to vote for close directly

Comment: I didn't downvote to auto-delete it @Cody :-); don't know enough about the subject and the question didn't seem to be that appalling that I could tell if needed it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [auto-deletion mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) already in place, according to which:

- The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days.
- The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.

In case the OP doesn't want an answer anymore then the question can be self-deleted or self-answered.

Comment: take a look at my comment for Cody Gray answer please

Answer (score 0):

If you want a moderator to *summarily* delete it, there are a few criteria that have to be present:

- It needs to be a really bad question that no other user has a reasonable chance of ever stumbling upon through searching (negative score questions are a plus)
- There should be no upvoted answers
- It should have had some sort of community interaction (a closed question is a plus).

As is stands, that question is not a negatively scored, it has an answer with two upvotes, and it isn't closed.

I don't see a basis to summarily delete it as a moderator, but that doesn't mean the community can't choose to close and delete it.

Comment: However, being posted here will surely lead to down voting.

Comment: As you can see the answer was given after I have started discussion here. At the time I wanted to have it closed / deleted - it was with 0 answer and - it is more important for me - the author of the question didnt provide futhter information he was asked for in the comments

Comment: And I havent downvoted your answer )

Comment: @MikroDel My answer gives the moderator stance on what to do with these types of questions.  That doesn't preclude you from getting the community to act on its own.  I received a flag on that question that essentially asked me to delete it, my post explains specifically and generally why we don't do that as moderators.

Comment: Sure - and your stance was based on the question after Cody Gray has posted the answer to it... At the time I have startet this topic - it wasnt any answeres to the question we are discussing